# Products can not be added to cart by click "Add to cart" for second time

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, addtocart, shopping-cart

I have Related products block in my product description page. I have configured a particular product's Minimum Qty = 5. So users can only buy products in multiples of 5.

Below is the screenshot of adding the simple product of MinQty(5) to cart from the related products block. The product is added successfully by Ajax and the minicart is updated and Network tab shows response 200.

**Succesful addition of product to cart (ss1):**
[image: product added to cart successfully]

But the issue is, When i click "Add to cart" for the second time the product with MinQty(5) **is not getting added** to cart. Even though the network tab show 200 response for the request. Below is the screenshot of not able to add products second time.

[image: Not able to add product second time]

I found this issue in Magento 2.1.9 version.
I am using Amasty_Cart for Ajax Add to cart.

Please help me, what's wrong in second time ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by addding 'qty' parameter to add to cart url.

File Location Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/lists/items.phtml

```
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId(),'qty' => $block->getMinimalQty($_item)])
```